# SQL Count from two tables

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a database with information about customers, stores, purchases, products, etc. I'm interested in how many customers live in each city. I found this by:

```
SELECT city, count(cID) FROM customer GROUP BY city
```

This gives the following table:

```
| City          | # |
+---------------+---+
| Amsterdam     | 4 |
| New York City | 2 |
| London        | 1 |
```

Now I'm not only interested in the cities where customers live. I'd also like to have the cities in which there is a store and where no customers live in the table. Like this:

```
| City          | # |
+---------------+---+
| Amsterdam     | 4 |
| New York City | 2 |
| London        | 1 |
| Los Angeles   | 0 |
```

Short, I'd like to count customers that live in each city that occurs in the customers table, the store table or both.

The tables look like this:
*customer*(**cID**, cName, street, city) and
*store*(**sID**, sName, street, city)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: do you have any table called 'City'? If not then from where you are getting city names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  c.city, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.cID) AS [#]
FROM customer c
GROUP BY c.city

UNION

SELECT  s.city,
        0 AS [#]
FROM store s
LEFT JOIN customer c ON s.city = c.city
WHERE c.cID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` between store table and the customer table, to also get cities without any customers!

```
SELECT s.city, count(*)
FROM store s
LEFT JOIN customer c ON s.city = c.city
GROUP BY s.city
```

Also, as @Akhter Alamin Farhan commented, don't you have a `cities` table? So instead of storing city names over and over again, just store them once and use  cityid in store and customer tables.

Comment: This does not create the result I'm looking for, it for example counts 2 for a city in which no customers live, but that have 2 stores

Comment: I replaced the count(*) by count(DISTINCT c.cID). This looks more like the desired result. Except that the cities in which customers live but where does not exist a store are left out

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with UNION ALL

```
SELECT someColumn,someColumn,NULL
FROM   someTable

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, NULL, someColumn
FROM   nextTable/orSameTable
```

Null is place where u will put next result that u want from another query